# MySQL Not Matching First Word Of String

Tags: mysql

TableA contains the following

```
key | value
------------
1   | this is a string
2   | another string
```

If I do

`SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE value LIKE '%string%'`

It works just fine every time, along with any other substring lookup.  But for some reason the first word never matches ie:

`SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE value LIKE '%this%' OR value LIKE '%another%'`

Is this normal?  How do I work around this problem?  I've tried an additional `OR` set to match `'this%'` and `'another%'`, however it does not help.

Comment: It should work. But if its not then there must be issue with character case somewhere. Try UCASE/LCASE with your query

Comment: @Ankur140290 : Actually with LIKE it shouldn't matter

Comment: @MateoBarahona I agree. But user has to be sure that the string is `this` and not `This` or something else. Since the query is not working, there should be case problem

Comment: Yes, I do have it going to lowercase, but even in a controlled environment where I'm using the values above it doesn't match the first letter.  Even `'%his%'` or `'%nother%'` work

Comment: How strange, i've recreated the case and it's perfectly working... Can you give us the full details about the table ?

Comment: Just a side note : don't use **key** or **value** as field names, it's bad practice.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Comment: The first column is INT, the latter is VARCHAR(250).  Table is MyISAM

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/badf4/1). See [9.3 Keywords and Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html).

Comment: Right.  I don't remember having this issue in the past either.  The MySql installation is current and fresh built on Centos 6.  If anyone has any other ideas to test, please let me know.  In the meantime a quick fix I'm chopping the first character off all user searches and it seems to work.